# How do you determine that the characteristic polynomial is the minimal polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the matrix A be:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}4&-14&5\\1&-4&2\\1&-6&4\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P(A)=-(\lambda -2)(\lambda-1)^2$$

First question: Sometimes I see people omit the "-", is that ok to do? i.e. $P(A)=(\lambda -2)(\lambda-1)^2$. I actually I see a lot of people just omit the negative sign, why is that? I know when you set the whole thing to 0, the negative sign doesn't play a role anymore, but is that the common practice?

Second question: calculation of the minimal polynomial, I tried to divide each factor, but nothing worked out. So I used a calculator, it turns out the characteristic polynomial is the minimal polynomial. But for that to be true, I think the characteristic polynomial needs to have distinct factors right? But clearly in this case we do not. So how is that possible?

I know there are a lot of similar questions, I went through a lot of those, couldn't find an answer that answers my question..

Comment: Some people define the characteristic polynomial to be $\det(A-\lambda I)$, others define it to be $\det(\lambda I-A)$; that explains a difference of negative signs (in odd dimensions). Your statement "But for that to be true, I think the characteristic polynomial needs to have distinct factors right?" is incorrect: It's true that if the characteristic polynomial has distinct roots then it is automatically the minimal polynomial, but you're asserting the converse which is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The characteristic and the minimal polynomial of a matrix**

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. We associate two polynomials to $A$:

1. The characteristic polynomial of A can defined as $F(X) = \det(X ·I −A)$, where
   $X$ is the variable of the polynomial, and $I$ represents the identity matrix. $F(X)$
   is a *monic* polynomial of degree $n$.
2. The minimal polynomial of $A$ which we will denote by $\mu(X)$, is defined by the
   following properties:

- $\mu(X)$ is *monic* (It means the leading coefficient is  $1$),
- $\mu(A)$ = 0,
- $\mu(X)$ is the *monic polynomial* of the smallest possible degree such that
  $\mu(A) = 0$
- If $g(X)$ is another polynomial, then $g(A) = 0$ if and only if  $\mu(X)$ divides $g(X)$.
- $F(X)$ is a multiple of  $\mu(X)$

Comment: I left math but there was some other method of finding *Algebraic multiplicity* and *geometric multiplicity* (smthing I don't remember now) I'll be happy if some1 can add their answer